# Automatically generate day of Month in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

How can I generate the day of month automatically, without hardcoding, as a parameter value in the red box. For instance if the day 15th, the parameter value, in the red box, shall generate value 15. This is used as a default value.

*I'm using SQL server 2012 DW.
*Data source is SSAS.
*If possible you also can propose solution to generate today's year.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on the built in date functions that are available.

You'll be able to achieve what you need by using `Today` or `Now` and `DatePart`

eg.

To return the current month: `=DatePart(DateInterval.Month, Today())`